# Documentation of a software project

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

I am working with a team that works on a very large software project, we have tons of Documentation that is written in MS WORD format with nohyperlinked indexes, no search ability.
Everyday we waste our time trying to find the exact document or reference.

I was thinking if there was way or even a professional tool that would convert all this into a wiki format and maybe with a little manual (painful) help be organised into something that improves the accessibility.
I use Google Desktop Search to make my life a little easier but its not the best solution

I just want to know if any of you faced similar problems and possible solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Confluence wiki](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/tour/microsoft-office-connector.jsp) lets you import Word documents. I've been told it's a really good wiki with a lot of features.

Answer (score 2):

### Open Source: Trac Wiki

The [Trac Wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWiki) system is a popular open source option. There's even a thread on another Stack Exchange site about converting [Word documents into the Track Wiki format](https://superuser.com/questions/21408/converting-word-documents-into-a-trac-wiki-format). Some large scale or notable users of Trac include Red Hat, Django, Handbrake and SourceForge.

### Commercial: Confluence

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview) is another popular option, as mentioned by Alex Korban. A good example of a large-scale use of it is the [Application Server 7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Documentation) community documentation of software company JBoss.

### 2015 Update - PressGang and Corilla

I'll just add a quick update that I agree so strongly with this problem of discoverable content and collaboration that I've worked on solving it in a few different projects.

#### PressGang (the prototype)

Please refer to the [PressGang CCMS](http://pressgang-ccms.github.io/) project for an idea of what we did at Red Hat to build tools to solve this. The lead engineer did a [run-through video](https://vimeo.com/54986436) that you can see on Vimeo, and I've created a public Amazon AMI if you wish to try it. It's not being maintained but it's all open source. Check out the repository or get involved in [the community fork](http://writewithhugo.com/).

#### Corilla (the product)

That was an amazing experience to be a part of and inspired me to spin out [Corilla](http://corilla.co/), an open source technical writing startup tackling exactly the problems you mention. This will have both a commercial/enterprise version available as well as open source community version. There's a beta currently running that I would [encourage you to get involved with](http://corilla.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=74294760fc0f23d4d652649da&id=a083c38be0) - the problems you're experiencing will be great to shape the solutions being built.

Comment: This question defines the most common usage of Confluence. It is excellent for storing documentation in format which is easily discoverable, editable and exportable (to PDF, Word .doc, HTML).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about tools to convert MS Word to a Wiki, but if you save your documentation in ODF (The XML format from OpenDocument) it should be possible to import the documents in your own program, or transform them using XSL, and output them in Wiki format.

In the process you can try to guess some links based on string matching.

The difficult part, in a team used to write documentation in a word processor (without even using word processing basic features like indexes, table of contents and hyperlinks), is to convince them to use another system that is not a typewriter.